# Application crash with slow response to input events

Tags: android, crash

I have 2 boards with same imx6d CPU and 2G memorys. The OS on them are both Android 5.1 but from different vendor. I installed an app on them, one of them works well while another always crash when I click the window. Logcat shows that an ANR error causes the problem.

```
E/ActivityManager( 2803): ANR in com.mm.android.direct.gdmsspadLite (com.mm.android.direct.gdmsspadLite/com.mm.android.direct.gdmsspad.MainActivity)
E/ActivityManager( 2803):   51% 5968/com.mm.android.direct.gdmsspadLite: 39% user + 11% kernel / faults: 3483 minor
E/ActivityManager( 2803):   103% 5968/com.mm.android.direct.gdmsspadLite: 50% user + 53% kernel / faults: 746 minor
E/ActivityManager( 2803):     98% 5968/ct.gdmsspadLite: 48% user + 50% kernel
E/ActivityManager( 2803):     1.9% 6379/ct.gdmsspadLite: 0% user + 1.9% kernel
W/ActivityManager( 2803):   Force finishing activity com.mm.android.direct.gdmsspadLite/com.mm.android.direct.gdmsspad.MainActivity
I/ActivityManager( 2803): Killing 5968:com.mm.android.direct.gdmsspadLite/u0a38 (adj 0): user request after error
```

And I found that the problem board show warnings like :

```
D/dalvikvm( 5721): No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/app-lib/com.mm.android.direct.gdmsspadLite-1/libdvr.so ,skipping init
```

Dose the failed JNI-OnLoad lead to slow response and finally cause crash?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that default dalvik.heapsize and dalvik.heapgrowthlimit are too little for my app. I enlarge these and it is less likely that errors will occur. However, it finally crashes after 2 minutes of the high-frequency test. Then I enlarge the response time of ANR and it stands the test for more than 3 hours.